# Measure total state size of a Flink job

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am new to Flink and I want to measure the total state size of my flink Job in order to perform some measurements for a university project.
I am using HashMapStateBackend and as I know state is stored in Taskmanagers Heap.

Is there any effective way to measure state using web ui or something else?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the `HashMapStateBackend` state holds all of its objects on the Java heap. Flink does come bundled with an available web interface that can be useful for viewing logs, exceptions, and as you might guess - monitoring resource usage.

You can find information about the heap usage specifically from the web interface of your job under the **Task Manager > Metrics section:**

[image]

Accessing the UI can vary depending on your deployment strategy or how you are running the jobs, but it should be trivial to access. This will allow you to see how the heap is growing as well as other common memory-related issues as your job processes data (i.e. JVM Metaspace, etc.).

Comment: Yes I have already found this section,but the heap also contains other things except of state so using change of heap size will not be so accurate. I think i will try to approximate state size by the total size of  elements that are saved on that.I have MapState and ListState so i will use the entries and get method respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have checkpointing enabled? If yes, you can look at the size of the checkpoint.